# Google Adword Api integration with php

Tags: javascript, php

How can we integrate google Adwords Api to a php application.Do we need to create a manager account and access devoloper token for accessing the Adword Api.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries

Answer (score 1):

Refer these links : [how to integrate adwords API in my website using PHP library](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/AdWords-Tracking-and-Reporting/how-to-integrate-adwords-API-in-my-website-using-PHP-library/td-p/305481)

[Google Ads API PHP Client Library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib)